# Recover an plug-in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I want to take the pictures grid plug-in code from this site : http://www.systran.fr/

I get the JS code but I don't how keep the CSS code from this div

Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gridShow {
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 421px
}

.gridShow ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -1px
}

.gridShow ul li {
    background: #009cd3;
    width: 319px;
    height: 210px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
    display: none
}

.gridShow ul li:hover {
    background: url('../img/common/bg-item-gridshow.png?1376664734')
}

.gridShow ul li.active .txt-container {
    background: url('../img/common/bg-item-gridshow.png?1376664734')
}

.gridShow ul li.active h3 {
    visibility: visible
}

.gridShow ul li.active .btn, .gridShow ul li.active body #container .post .infos p + a, body #container .post .infos .gridShow ul li.active p + a, .gridShow ul li.active button, .gridShow ul li.active input[type='submit'], .gridShow ul li.active .form-container #cform .upload-box .upload-btn, .form-container #cform .upload-box .gridShow ul li.active .upload-btn, .gridShow ul li.active .form-container #cform-popup .upload-box .upload-btn, .form-container #cform-popup .upload-box .gridShow ul li.active .upload-btn, .gridShow ul li.active .grayarea .thumb + div h5 + a, .grayarea .thumb + div .gridShow ul li.active h5 + a, .gridShow ul li.active .grayarea .thumb + div h5 + p > a, .grayarea .thumb + div .gridShow ul li.active h5 + p > a, .gridShow ul .discover-list li.active a, .discover-list .gridShow ul li.active a, .gridShow ul li.active .studies-list .logo + div + div a, .studies-list .logo + div + div .gridShow ul li.active a, .gridShow ul li.active .press-list div + div a, .press-list div + div .gridShow ul li.active a, .gridShow ul li.active .home #sbox .sbox_btn a, .home #sbox .sbox_btn .gridShow ul li.active a, .gridShow ul li.active .reseller-box a[href*="http"], .reseller-box .gridShow ul li.active a[href*="http"] {
    visibility: visible
}

.gridShow ul li h3 {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s
}

.gridShow ul li p {
    font-family: DinBold;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.gridShow ul li .btn, .gridShow ul li body #container .post .infos p + a, body #container .post .infos .gridShow ul li p + a, .gridShow ul li button, .gridShow ul li input[type='submit'], .gridShow ul li .form-container #cform .upload-box .upload-btn, .form-container #cform .upload-box .gridShow ul li .upload-btn, .gridShow ul li .form-container #cform-popup .upload-box .upload-btn, .form-container #cform-popup .upload-box .gridShow ul li .upload-btn, .gridShow ul li .grayarea .thumb + div h5 + a, .grayarea .thumb + div .gridShow ul li h5 + a, .gridShow ul li .grayarea .thumb + div h5 + p > a, .grayarea .thumb + div .gridShow ul li h5 + p > a, .gridShow ul .discover-list li a, .discover-list .gridShow ul li a, .gridShow ul li .studies-list .logo + div + div a, .studies-list .logo + div + div .gridShow ul li a, .gridShow ul li .press-list div + div a, .press-list div + div .gridShow ul li a, .gridShow ul li .home #sbox .sbox_btn a, .home #sbox .sbox_btn .gridShow ul li a, .gridShow ul li .reseller-box a[href*="http"], .reseller-box .gridShow ul li a[href*="http"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s
}

.gridShow ul li img {
    display: none
}

.gridShow .txt-container {
    padding: 25px 18px 25px 25px;
    position: relative;
    height: 210px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20
}

.gridShow .incruste {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 319px !important;
    height: 210px !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.gridShow .incruste.ontop {
    z-index: 1
}

.gridShow .filter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 319px !important;
    height: 210px !important;
    z-index: 2
}

.gridShow .shAdapt {
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```